# What is the difference between pipeline and make_pipeline in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I got this from the `sklearn` webpage:

- **Pipeline**: Pipeline of transforms with a final estimator
- **Make_pipeline**: Construct a Pipeline from the given estimators. This is a shorthand for the Pipeline constructor.

But I still do not understand when I have to use each one. Can anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The only difference is that `make_pipeline` generates names for steps automatically.

Step names are needed e.g. if you want to use a pipeline with model selection utilities (e.g. GridSearchCV). With grid search you need to specify parameters for various steps of a pipeline:

```
pipe = Pipeline([('vec', CountVectorizer()), ('clf', LogisticRegression()])
param_grid = [{'clf__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}
gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid)
gs.fit(X, y)
```

compare it with make_pipeline:

```
pipe = make_pipeline(CountVectorizer(), LogisticRegression())     
param_grid = [{'logisticregression__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}
gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid)
gs.fit(X, y)
```

So, with `Pipeline`:

- names are explicit, you don't have to figure them out if you need them;
- name doesn't change if you change estimator/transformer used in a step, e.g. if you replace LogisticRegression() with LinearSVC() you can still use `clf__C`.

`make_pipeline`:

- shorter and arguably more readable notation;
- names are auto-generated using a straightforward rule (lowercase name of an estimator).

When to use them is up to you :) I prefer make_pipeline for quick experiments and Pipeline for more stable code; a rule of thumb: IPython Notebook -> make_pipeline; Python module in a larger project -> Pipeline. But it is certainly not a big deal to use make_pipeline in a module or Pipeline in a short script or a notebook.

Comment: Could you tell me where it is documented that the name of `LogisticRegression()`'s estimator is `logisticregression`? I had to set a grid search for `OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())` but I don't know what name refers to it.

Comment: @KubiK888 it is documented at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html - "their names will be set to the lowercase of their types automatically"

Comment: But what about `OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())`, I have tried all of the following: `'onevsrestclassifier_linearsvc__C', 
 onevsrestclassifier_linearsvc_estimator__C', 'onevsrestclassifier__C',       'linearsvc__C', 'onevsrestclassifier__linearsvc__C', 'onevsrestclassifier-linearsvc__C',  'onevsrestclassifier_linearsvc_estimator__C', 'estimator__C'`, they all give me `Check the list of available parameters with "estimator.get_params().keys()"`.

Answer (score 2):

If we look at [the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/364c77e047ca08a95862becf40a04fe9d4cd2c98/sklearn/pipeline.py#L872), `make_pipeline()` creates a `Pipeline` object, so they are equivalent. As mentioned by @Mikhail Korobov, the only difference is that `make_pipeline()` doesn't admit estimator names and they are set to the lowercase of their types. In other words, `type(estimator).__name__.lower()` is used to create estimator names ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/364c77e047ca08a95862becf40a04fe9d4cd2c98/sklearn/pipeline.py#L807)). So it's really a simpler form of building a pipeline.

On a related note, to get parameter names you can use `get_params()`. This is useful if you want to know the parameter names for `GridSearch()`. The parameter names are [created by](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2a2772a87b6c772dc3b8292bcffb990ce27515a8/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py#L49) concatenating the estimator names with their kwargs recursively (e.g. `max_iter` of a `LogisticRegression()` is stored as `'logisticregression__max_iter'` or `C` parameter in `OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression())` as `'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__C'`; the latter because when written using kwargs, it is `OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=LogisticRegression())`).

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline, Pipeline
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification()
pipe = make_pipeline(PCA(), LogisticRegression())

print(pipe.get_params())

# {'memory': None,
#  'steps': [('pca', PCA()), ('logisticregression', LogisticRegression())],
#  'verbose': False,
#  'pca': PCA(),
#  'logisticregression': LogisticRegression(),
#  'pca__copy': True,
#  'pca__iterated_power': 'auto',
#  'pca__n_components': None,
#  'pca__n_oversamples': 10,
#  'pca__power_iteration_normalizer': 'auto',
#  'pca__random_state': None,
#  'pca__svd_solver': 'auto',
#  'pca__tol': 0.0,
#  'pca__whiten': False,
#  'logisticregression__C': 1.0,
#  'logisticregression__class_weight': None,
#  'logisticregression__dual': False,
#  'logisticregression__fit_intercept': True,
#  'logisticregression__intercept_scaling': 1,
#  'logisticregression__l1_ratio': None,
#  'logisticregression__max_iter': 100,
#  'logisticregression__multi_class': 'auto',
#  'logisticregression__n_jobs': None,
#  'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2',
#  'logisticregression__random_state': None,
#  'logisticregression__solver': 'lbfgs',
#  'logisticregression__tol': 0.0001,
#  'logisticregression__verbose': 0,
#  'logisticregression__warm_start': False}

# use the params from above to construct param_grid
param_grid = {'pca__n_components': [2, None], 'logisticregression__C': [0.1, 1]}
gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid)
gs.fit(X, y)

best_score = gs.score(X, y)
```

Circling back to `Pipeline` vs `make_pipeline`; `Pipeline` gives you more flexibility in naming parameters but if you name each estimator using lowercase of its type, then `Pipeline` and `make_pipeline` they will both have the same params and steps attributes.

```py
pca = PCA()
lr = LogisticRegression()
make_pipe = make_pipeline(pca, lr)
pipe = Pipeline([('pca', pca), ('logisticregression', lr)])

make_pipe.get_params() == pipe.get_params()   # True
make_pipe.steps == pipe.steps                 # True
```