# Last step of Pipeline should implement fit or be the string 'passthrough'

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to build simple pipeline:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline


make_pipeline([
    ('PolynomialFeatures', PolynomialFeatures(include_bias=False)),
    ('Lasso', Lasso(fit_intercept=True, max_iter=1000))])
```

And I'm getting error:

```
TypeError: Last step of Pipeline should implement fit or be the string 'passthrough'. '[('PolynomialFeatures', PolynomialFeatures(include_bias=False)), ('Lasso', Lasso())]' (type <class 'list'>) doesn't
```

What is wrong ? How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `pipeline` instead of `make_pipeline` due to you provided the steps with names (more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708077/what-is-the-difference-between-pipeline-and-make-pipeline-in-scikit)!).

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline, Pipeline


Pipeline([
    ('PolynomialFeatures', PolynomialFeatures(include_bias=False)),
    ('Lasso', Lasso(fit_intercept=True, max_iter=1000))])
```

output:

```
Pipeline(steps=[('PolynomialFeatures', PolynomialFeatures(include_bias=False)),
                ('Lasso', Lasso())])
```